# __getattr__ within a module in python

Tags: python, iteration, getattr

I am working with python. I want to know whether or not any method is existed or not in same module. I think `getattr()` does this but I couldn't do. Here is sample code saying what really I want to do with.

```
#python module is my_module.py
def my_func():
    # I want to check the existence of exists_method
    if getattr(my_module, exists_method):
       print "yes method "
       return
    print "No method"
def exists_method():
    pass
```

My main task is to dynamically call defined method. If it is not defined, just skip operations with that method and continue. I have a dictionary of data from which on the basis of keys I define some necessary methods to operate on corresponding values. for e.g. data is  `{"name":"my_name","address":"my_address","...":"..."}`. Now I define a method called `name()` which I wanted to know dynamically it really exists or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look for the *name* as a string; and I'd use `hasattr()` here to test for that name:

```
if hasattr(my_module, 'exists_method'):
    print 'Method found!"
```

This works if `my_module.exists_method` exists, but not if you run this code *inside* `my_module`.

If `exists_method` is contained in the *current* module, you would need to use `globals()` to test for it:

```
if 'exists_method' in globals():
    print 'Method found!'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dir](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir),

```
>>> import time
>>> if '__name__' in dir(time):
...     print 'Method found'
... 
Method found
```

Comment: If you closely see my post, you will definitely you find that your answer is not my solution. I already could do other things with your style. Anyway thanks for your reply.